# Sharepoint 2013 Document Library Choice column

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a choice column with over 100 choices, need to give the ability to choose multiple values.  Is there a way to make it into a dropdown list with multiple selection?  right now the checkbox list is huge and spans multiple pages.  or is that a javascript workaround
 [image: screenshot of column],

i cant use infopath because this is on a document library and not a list

thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML and JavaScript/jQuery to create dropdown with checkbox by yourself instead of using the OOB field.

Here is a demo of the dropdown with checkbox:

https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri

Then, you may need to use CSOM/Rest API to update the file properties in the library as you are using a custom field.

Information about how to use CSOM to update item:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code